# Maven test not terminating from jenkins/command line/eclipse after stopping execution

Tags: eclipse, maven, testing, jenkins, command-prompt

My pom.xml file:

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I have created a project in eclipse with maven+testNG

I have a total 23 test scenario's in testng

Problems are:

1. I run my project from eclipse --> Right click project --> run as --> maven install -- > project starts executing.  When I stop it at any time using "Terminate" button, executing stops from eclipse but actually process runs in background and all 23 tests scenarios continues to execute
2. Same thing happens when executing through command line by --> mvn test --> Ctrl+C -->Its asks Terminate process? Y/N? --> Y --> execution stops in foreground but process still runs in background and all 23 scenarios continues to execute.
3. And at last when I run a build of same maven project from jenkins and I stop its execution, process stops in foreground but test scenario's keep on executing in background.

I need help on where problem is and how to totally stop execution. Thanks in advance

My setup:

- Java 8,
- Eclipse Mars.2,
- Jenkins 2.7.1,
- Maven 3.3.9,

Comment: Not sure if surefire forks by default. You could try adding <shutdown>kill</shutdown> to your configuration.  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/shutdown.html

Comment: Tried. not working.. i have also tried by adding <forkCount>0</forkCount> in configuration tag, that also did not work

Comment: I am also having problems 2 and 3. I execute my tests from IntelliJ and terminate them without problems. However when I run them through a maven command and terminate it, the java process isn't killed. I can kill it manually using task manager but I also would like to know how to correctly shut it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use forkMode=never in pom.xml file to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Jenkins bug

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28968

In certain circumstances this can be expected behaviour.